# What are the differences in HP/Shield/Barrier and damage stats between multiplayer difficulties?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I see a lot of assumptions and guesswork, but can anyone confirm (with a source) the differences between HP/Shield/Barrier pools, and the damage output modifiers applied in each separate challenge? BioWare is very vague when it comes to concrete numbers of damage, health, exact modifier values or anything for that matter.

Mathematics preferred for theorycrafting. Thanks!

Comment: If you take a look at the [multiplayer patch notes](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9544143/1#9660503), you'll see that enemies have more health/armor/shields on the higher difficulties.  Since this is constantly in flux its hard to say for sure exactly what those numbers are.

Comment: I highly doubt their damage output is increased. Units like banshees already do an extraordinary amount of damage. Upping their damage in gold would mean instant death to the player.

Answer (score 1):

**BRONZE Stats**(Category="GethPrime", CategoryData=((StatName="MaxHealth",StatRange=(X=5000.0f,Y=7500.0f)),(StatName="MaxShields",StatRange=(X=3500.0f,Y=5250.0f)),(StatName="ShieldDrone_MaxHealth",StatRange=(X=300.0f,Y=375.0f)),(StatName="Turret_MaxHealth",StatRange=(X=250.0f,Y=325.0f))

**GOLD Stats**(Category="GethPrime", CategoryData=((StatName="MaxHealth",StatRange=(X=11250.0f,Y=16875.0f)),(StatName="MaxShields",StatRange=(X=7875.0f,Y=11812.0f)),(StatName="ShieldDrone_MaxHealth",StatRange=(X=300.0f,Y=375.0f)),(StatName="Turret_MaxHealth",StatRange=(X=250.0f,Y=325.0f))

Every other stat is the same, for how much the shield drone heals and how often, how often drone and turret spawn, etc...

I am unsure for the difference between X stats and Y stats, my best guess is the Y stats is when it is "target" in the select missions to kill the 4 targets, because they are always harder to kill.

If want more information or on a specific monster leave a comment and I can update for that specific monster, but those numbers should be true for every monster. Which is about a 50% increase in health/shields per difficulty level.

Comment: Spawns are also increased -- continuing the Geth example, the first wave in Bronze will only have Troopers, while Silver adds in Rocket Troopers. I haven't played Gold enough to really know much about it, though.

Comment: Yes, but his question only pretains to the health/barries of monsters and if they do more damage. To describe 11 waves of gold takes a lot more than 500 characters. I have wondered if some of the lower enemies (canniables/maruders) get an increase in fire rate, but never looked. But appears do not get an increase in damage.

Answer (score 1):

## About enemies' endurance.

Each multiplayer difficulty level increases enemies' health and defenses by 50%. You can see that reflected by numbers NoNameNeeded provided: say, Prime's maxshields "Y" is 11812 on gold, which is 1.5*1.5=2.25 times lower than on bronze (and indeed, 5250*2.25=11812.5). Assuming that .5 is rounded down, it is a precise match. Other numbers follow the pattern as well. Perhaps there are some exceptions to this, but i don't think there are many, if any at all.

However, HP/Shield/Barrier is not all there is to enemies' survivalability; it would be a mistake to think that enemies are exactly 50% more "fat" per each difficulty increase in multiplayer. Because, apart from increased health and defenses, higher difficulty enemies also get other parameters improved: [shield/barrier regeneration times](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0ArNVjEsDluBFdEZXSU5GTkVwVmYwcm1FU3AyUHl6eHc&gid=1), [shield/barrier damage gate](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/347/index/9822648#10321708), armor's potency ([mentioned here on the Bioware forums](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/10894675/1) among some other features also related to this question).

As one can easily see, all these "other" boosts are not based on +50%-extra-per-difficulty pattern: some are raising slower than that, while armor's potency increases faster than that.

I can't find any source, but i remember reading something about enemies having less "reaction time" in higher difficulties, too. Please don't quote me on that though...

## About enemies' firepower.

I don't have any source nor any precise number on this one. However, I am pretty sure that (at least majority of) enemies get higher damage in higher difficulties. Comparing how my krogan battlemasters are able to run silver games without major problems while not using any +shield equipment, but get fried on gold trying to do very same things if I am not using at least level 2 cyclonic modulator (which provides +60% to his barrier), I'd say that damage of (at least majority of) enemies is boosted by about 50% per difficulty as well. Additional (more than extra 50%) damage is received per second (average) in practice, of course, due to higher number of enemies in average gold-match combat situation.